# Distribute work stored in table to multiple processes

Tags: akka, distributed-computing, actor

I have a database table where each row represents a work to be done. This table is filled up/receive work through a rest API. Apart from a rest-service taking up the work, I have another service which uses actors to process this work.

I need suggestions in distributing this work evenly across these workers. This work is not one time, it is kind of done at an interval until user deletes that.

Therefore I need a mechanism where

1. The work as it comes is distributed evenly.
2. If the second service(work consumer) fails it can again boot up with all the records in table and distribute the work again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general outline of a solution is to use Akka Cluster, Cluster Sharding, and Akk Cluster Singleton.  When the cluster is considered formed (generally when some minimum number of members have joined the cluster), you start the Cluster Sharding system (sharding work items by the DB's primary key) and then a Cluster Singleton will read the DB table and send work items to Cluster Sharding for distribution among the nodes of the cluster.  Akka Streams and particularly Alpakka's Slick JDBC integration may prove useful within the singleton.  Another cluster singleton to periodically check on jobs may also be useful to recover from cluster node failures (but see below for something to consider there).

Two notes:

- If using Cluster Sharding and Cluster Singleton, you probably want to consider what happens in a split-brain situation: this is a distributed system and the probability of a split-brain eventually happening can be presumed to be 100%.  In the split-brain scenario, you will very likely have the same jobs being performed simultaneously by different sides of the split, so you need to ask if that's acceptable in your use-case.

  If not, then you will need a component which monitors the communications between nodes in your cluster to detect a split-brain and takes steps to resolve the condition: Lightbend's [Split Brain Resolver](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-enhancements/current/split-brain-resolver.html) is a good choice if you aren't interested in implementing this yourself.
- In a related vein, if the jobs consist of many steps which must be performed, a question to ask is, if a cluster or node fails after completing, say, eight of ten steps, is it acceptable to redo steps 1-8 vs. starting with step 9?  If the answer to this is "no", then you'll need to persist the intermediate state of the job.  Akka Persistence is a great choice here, though you may want to read up on event sourcing.  If using Persistence with Cluster Sharding and Cluster Singleton, it should be noted, you will almost certainly need to handle split-brains (see previous item).

Comment: I have already implemented a solution but yours also makes sense. So what I did instead of creating a Cluster singleton to distribute the work I have assigned each node an index from 0 to n-1. Now each node in the cluster will work on the DB rows with **mod(id, n)==index**. There were some drawbacks like ids should be evenly distributed(ideally incremented) and nodes should be predetermined so that we can assign a number to it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Each actor represents one row of the work table.

```
class WorkActor(workId: String)(implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: ActorMaterializer) extends Actor {

  // read the record from table or whereever you want to read
  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    logger.info("WorkActor start ===> " + self)
  }

   override def receive: Receive = {
    case _ => {}
  }
}
```

2. Create an Akka cluster sharding region to dispatch the request from rest api to corresponding actor. Calling startShardingRegion function to return an actorRef. Then you could send the message to this sharding actorRef by rest API, and then corresponding will help you handle the message.

```
  final case class CommandEnvelope(id: String, payload: Any)

  def startShardingRegion(role: String)(implicit system: ActorSystem) = {
    ClusterSharding(system).start(
      typeName = role,
      entityProps = Props(classOf[WorkActor]),
      settings = ClusterShardingSettings(system),
      extractEntityId = ClusterConfig.extractEntityId,
      extractShardId = ClusterConfig.extractShardId
    )
  }

// sharding key

object ClusterConfig {

  private val numberOfShards = 100

  val extractEntityId: ShardRegion.ExtractEntityId = {
    case CommandEnvelope(id, payload) => (id, payload)
  }

  val extractShardId: ShardRegion.ExtractShardId = {
    case CommandEnvelope(id, _) => (id.hashCode % numberOfShards).toString
    case ShardRegion.StartEntity(id) => (id.hashCode % numberOfShards).toString
  }


}
```

3. Read or recover the data from preStart function in the actor. There are many choice. You may read the uncompleted work from MQ (Kafka), Akka persistence (RDS, Cassandra) etc.
4. SBR has open source solution. That is an advanced topic if your business logic works.

```
https://github.com/TanUkkii007/akka-cluster-custom-downing
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I have already implemented a solution days ago. So instead of making my REST API know that it is interacting with an actor system, I have used Akka HTTP to host the actor system as a microservice.